# How to Retry AWS Glue Job When The Job Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue

I would like to retry a job, when it return a `Timeout` status. Is it possible to do this in AWS Glue Job using terrafrom? I've tried setting up MaxRetries to 3 (times) and Timeout to 1 (minutes), when the job Timeout, it didn't retry.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retry only works when the **job failed** and not when it timeouts. You would need to implement custom logic for that, e.g. `Event Bridge` listening on `Glue` timeout events -> invoking a `Lambda` that starts your job again.